# Undeclared path 'provider'/SQL syntax error with QueryDSL and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, subquery, querydsl

(The following are not my actual entities but they are analogous in structure)

I'm currently trying to write a controller method which returns pages of the recipients of a given provider.

Provider class looks like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Provider")
public class Provider {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="joinDate")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime joinDate;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="Provider_Recipients",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="providerId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="recipientId"))
    public Collection<Recipient> recipients;

    public Provider() {
    }
}
```

Recipient class looks like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Recipients")
public class Recipient {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="type")
    @Column(name="value")
    @CollectionTable(
            name="Recipient_ProtoAttrs",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="recipientId"))
    public Map<String, String> attributes;

    public Long quantity;

    @Column(name="date")
   @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime date;

    public Recipient() {
        this.attributes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Recipient(Recipient old) {
         this.attributes = new HashMap<>(old.attributes);
         this.quantity = old.quantity;
         this.date = old.date;
    }
}
```

I'm using a mapping table between Provider table and the Recipients table.

Repository's findAll method:

```
@Override
public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

    JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
    JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate));

    Long total = countQuery.count();
    List<T> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.list(path) : Collections.<T> emptyList();

    return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, total);
}
```

And now for the issue. When trying the following query:

```
QProvider qProvider = QProvider.provider;
QRecipient qRecipient = QRecipient.recipient;
BooleanExpression exp = qRecipient.in(qProvider.recipients).and(qProvider.id.eq(providerId));
return providerRepo.findAll(exp, new PageRequest(pageNum, PAGE_SIZE));
```

I get

```
Undeclared path 'provider'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.
```

If I instead try:

```
QProvider qProvider = QProvider.provider;
QRecipient qRecipient = QRecipient.recipient;
BooleanExpression exp = qRecipient.in((CollectionExpression) new JPASubQuery()
    .from(qProvider)
    .where(qProvider.id.eq(providerId))
    .list(qProvider.recipients));
return providerRepo.findAll(exp, new PageRequest(pageNum, PAGE_SIZE));
```

then I get a SQL syntax error. Specifically, the generated subquery is

```
select . from Provider provider1_, Provider_Recipients recipients2_, Recipient recipient3_ where provider1_.id=recipients2_.providerId and recipient2_.recipientId=recipient3_.id and provider1_.id=?
```

I've tried several different ways of specifying the query and subquery, but I always get one of those two errors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Found a work around (or rather probably the way I should have been doing it in the first place):

Instead of:

```
BooleanExpression exp = qRecipient.in((CollectionExpression) new JPASubQuery()
    .from(qProvider)
    .where(qProvider.id.eq(providerId))
    .list(qProvider.recipients));
```

this:

```
BooleanExpression exp = qRecipient.id.in(new JPASubQuery()
    .from(qProvider).rightJoin(qProvider.recipients, qRecipient)
    .where(qProvider.id.eq(providerId))
    .list(qRecipient.id));
```

works as intended.